# Should it take more than a few seconds to ALTER a VIEW in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, view

I'm trying to alter a View that is just a table plus an additional calculated field, and it's now five minutes since I hit EXECUTE.  Is this normal?

Comment: Most likely a query is in progress that's using that view.

Comment: I'd go with your answer (but you've not put it in an answer), ;-) .  I'm the only user and I've closed down the Access DB that was connected to the server and then re-ran the code and it was instant.  Thanks.

Comment: No problem. @AaronBertrand's is better anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for blocking in `sys.dm_exec_requests`. On the window where you ran the alter on the view, you should see a spid (like 57 or 65) on the tab or in the status bar. Run this query (assuming your spid was 57):

```
SELECT last_wait_type,blocking_session_id 
  FROM sys.dm_exec_requests
  WHERE session_id = 57;
```

Chances are, `blocking_session_id` will not be NULL. If a session comes from there, you can quickly see what they ran (let's say it returned 62) by:

```
DBCC INPUTBUFFER(62);
```

Or you may have an extensive blocking chain, so you may have to keep plugging the new blocking spids into the top query to track down the lead blocker.

Once you find the lead blocker, you can determine what to do. You can let it finish, or you can try to kill it. Again, assuming the lead blocker is session_id 62:

```
KILL 62;
```

But in most cases you probably want to let it finish.

Comment: In my instance, all I needed was [The Coon]'s answer, I closed the infringing Access DB and it ran instantly.  Thanks for your very detailed answer, hopefully it will help someone else with a similar question out there.

Comment: Well yeah, this doesn't just happen to people using Access (especially since you didn't tell us you were using Access and had it open). :-)

Comment: If I'd realised it was because I had Access open (so I could tell you), I wouldn't have needed to ask LOL, sods law.  Thanks anyway.